# How can I get my code to wait till all the code in a loop executes before continuing?

Tags: jquery, callback, each

I'm iterating through a group of html elements using a jquery `each`. On each iteration I invoke a `get`. I want to keep track of the successful gets and output a count at the end.

```
var numSuccessful = 0;
$('.mySelector').each(function(){
    $.get('/myCfc.cfc?method=doSomething&id=' + $(this).attr('id'), 
        function(data){
            numSuccessful++;
    });
});
alert(numSuccessful + ' successful');
```

The problem with this code is that the each method starts off all the get calls and then continues to the alert before completing the gets - and before the numSuccessful variable is updated. On a test run, I ended up with "0 successful" instead of "4 successful" because the alert executed too quickly. How can I get the code to wait till all the gets complete before continuing? Is there a success callback for the entire "each" statement?

Comment: You could use [`jQuery.Callbacks`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Callbacks/) or [`.promise()`](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) - are you familiar this kind of JS?

Comment: `$('#mySelector').each`? IDs must be _unique_, your selector only selects the first element with id of `mySelector`.

Comment: I solved a similar problem using a two function loop: An external counter keeping track of the elements, the content of the 'each' construct block as one function, calling the callback function when done, and the callback executing the first function again if the counter is below the nr of elements.

Comment: @undefined - sorry, that was a typo. Should be $('.mySelector'), I'll update.

Comment: @m90 - no, can you elaborate?

Comment: @m90 I didn't now those methods, thanks!

Comment: It is important to remember that the $.get() method is asynchronous and the each() method will run through all the elements before getting the callback from the first invocation of $.get().  This is why you are alerting "0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `$.get` with `$.ajax` and set `async` setting to false.

```
$.ajax({
    url : '/myCfc.cfc',
    data : { 'method' : 'doSomething' , 'id' : $(this).attr('id') },
    async : false,
    success : function(data){
       numSuccessful++;
    }
});
```

By doing this script will wait until it will get response.

Comment: Thanks, this worked - there's just a syntax error in your code, you need curly braces around the body of the ajax call

Answer (score 1):

You can use a *recursive function*, try the following:

```
var num = 0;
var $ms = $('.mySelector');

function go() {
     $.get('/myCfc.cfc?method=doSomething&id='+$ms.eq(num).attr('id'), 
       function(data){
            num++;
            if ((num-1) == $ms.length) callback(); else go();
     }).error(callback)
}

function callback(){
  alert(num)
}

go()
```

Comment: maybe you mean `.error(callback)` instead of `.error(callback())` ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the promise returned by `$.ajax` to setup a flexible callback queue like this:

```
var requests = []; //Array containing all the ajax calls

for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    requests.push(
    $.ajax({
        url: '/echo/html', //this is because of jsfiddle.net
        type: 'post', //this one too
        success: function() {
           //whatever
        }
    }));
}

$.when.apply($, requests).then(function() { //.apply is needed as we want to pass an Array
  //called when all requests are done
}).fail(function(){ //this will be triggered when one of the requests fails
  //error handling can go here
});
```

See **[this working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ykjBZ/1/)** and read about **[`.when()` and `.then`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)**

In your case that would end up in:

```
var numSuccessful = 0;

var requests = $.makeArray($('.mySelector').map(function(){
    return $.ajax({
        url: '/myCfc.cfc?method=doSomething&id=' + this.id,
        type: 'GET'
    }).done(function(){
        numSuccessful++;
    });
}));

$.when.apply($, requests).then(function() {
    alert(numSuccessful + ' successful');
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var numSuccessful = 0;
var totalSelectors = $('#mySelector').length;
$('#mySelector').each(function(){
  $.get('/myCfc.cfc?method=doSomething&id=' + $(this).attr('id'), 
  function(data){
    numSuccessful++;
    if(!totalSelectors--) doneSelectors();
  });
});

function doneSelectors() {
  alert(numSuccessful + ' successful');
}
```

Note: The above function does NOT work properly! The `$.get()` does not notify on errors, so if you get any errors the final function will never run.

Instead you need to convert it to use the `$.ajax()` function. And define both success and failure callbacks. If you need help doing that let me know.